# Contructor con ciertos objetos me trae todos en null

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un problema con un contructor en java, ya que al momento de crear uno con datos que necesito me retorna todos los datos y solo completa los que uso y el resto se pone en "null".

//Model

```
private String professionalId;
private String name;
private String firstSurname;
private String secondSurname;
private String dni;
private Date birthdate;
private String gender;

 public Professional(String professionalId, String name, String firstSurname, String secondSurname) {
    this.professionalId = professionalId;
    this.name = name;
    this.firstSurname = firstSurname;
    this.secondSurname = secondSurname;
}
```

//Dao

//RowMapper

```
public MedicalAppointment mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    return new Professional(rs.getString()...etc);
```

//Consutla

```
   @Override
public List<MedicalAppointment> findProfessional() {
    final String SQL_GET_ALL = "select p.professional_id,\n" +
            "       p.name,\n" +
            "       p.first_surname,\n" +
            "       p.second_surname from professional as p";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_GET_ALL, new MedicalAppointmentMapper()); }
```

//Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/searchProfessional")
ResponseEntity<List<MedicalAppointment>> findProfessionalName(@RequestHeader("userId") String userId) throws UnknownHostException {
    auditCreator.create(WebUtils.getAudit(userId, "GET", "appointment"));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(appointmentFinder.findProfessional());
}
```

Y al momento de hacer la consulta me retorna asi

```
 {
    "professional": {
        "professionalId": "145d3b69-c74b-4261-a0a4-f4b54e1889fb",
        "name": "Juan",
        "firstSurname": "Quispe",
        "secondSurname": "Sanches",
        "dni": null,
        "birthdate": null,
        "gender": null
    },
},
```

Este solo es un prueba de como me retorna el resultado alguien sabe el porque?

Answer (score 0):

hola amigo por el poco código que pusiste puedo ver que todo esta bien creo que el problema estaría como este hecha la consulta a mi punto de vista, por que si te trae los otros datos y esos no y solo veo que le envías un parámetro a la misma y te retorna los de mas datos.

podrías tal vez revisar como estas realizando la consulta o si le falta algo al model.

Comment: Acabo de colocar la consulta que he echo.